# setting log path in default cstr

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j

In my default cstr i an instantiating my log4j logger wherein i want to send in log file dir path during run time.

My default cstr has this:

```
logger = new LoggerSetup().SetLogger(Logger.getLogger(ServiceController.class), "FileLogger", LogDirPath);
```

I have the path set in my properties file and i read that via

```
@Value("#{settings['ApplicationLogDirPath']}")
private String LogDirPath;
```

However as the cstr gets called before the `@Value` is wired up, the LogDirPath in the cstr is always null.

Is there another annotation that I should use else is there a better way?

What I am trying to achieve is to set the log4j log path set dynamically from log file in addition my controller has need for 2 loggers so that application level logs are logged to one spot and a long running database call [ controller calls biz layer ] writes to another location. the controller logs before calling the biz layer and then once the biz layer returns it logs that and hence 2 different log files. Customer needs this bizare logging so it is what it is

Comment: You may have to pass the path as a vm argument like `-DlogPath=<path>`

Comment: How does this work when i deploy?

Comment: what is the deployment process

Comment: BUild war file with eclipse, stop tomcat, place in webapps, start tomcat and app is deployed. stop tomcat, remove war file and restart tomcat

Comment: In that case it is not possbile, if you were using an installer we could have set the argument. Were is the source of the log location? is it loaded from a properties file?

Comment: yes, it is from a properties files

Comment: where is it located? is it located in the classpath?

Comment: src/main/webapps/web-inf/spring/customprops.properties

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25235/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user1361914)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ${log.dir} property substitution technique. Here's how:

```
String dynamicLog = // log directory somehow chosen...
Properties p = new Properties( Config.ETC + "/log4j.properties" );
p.put( "log.dir", dynamicLog ); // overwrite "log.dir"
PropertyConfigurator.configure( p );
```

[Following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825414/best-practice-on-configuring-log4j-properties-path) should also address your question.

Comment: I initially tried using the `@PostConstruct` but that seemed to be getting called twice when the application was launched in debug on server mode. The article you provided was much helpful and got to a solution similar to one proposed

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the property file manually and fetch the property

```
File resource = new File(SO15116168.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".").getFile());
File file = new File(resource.getParent()+"/spring","customprops.properties");
System.out.println(file);
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream(file));
String property = p.getProperty("ApplicationLogDirPath");
```

replace `SO15116168` with your class.