# File Not Found: Java I/O Issue

Tags: java

I cannot get my file to read in my program... Why will the program not find the file? Am I not importing the file correctly?

Any feedback is much appreciated! Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ArraysIO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //local variables
        //create array
        String[] data = new String[100];
        //set up counter
        int count = 0;

        // Create File and Scanner objects inside main
        File file = new File("sampledata1.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        // Read in the names from the file
        while (inputFile.hasNext() && count < data.length) {
           data[count] = inputFile.nextLine();
           count++;
        }

        // Remember to close the file ASAP
        inputFile.close();


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: From which directory are you running your application and where is the file you're trying to open located?

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace you're getting?

Comment: Add `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());` before the `Scanner` and see what file you are trying to access. You will find, that that file does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I did not have the file in the correct location and I was not printing the scanner. Here is the working code that I had! Thank you for the help everyone!

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArraysIO2 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


            // Create File and Scanner objects inside main
            File file = new File("sampledata1.txt");
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println(inputFile.next());
            }
            inputFile.close();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("sampledata1.txt");
```

Is asking java to refer for a file located in current directory with name `sampledata1.txt`

now current directory is from where you launched your program generally, if you want to know where the current working directory points to you can check it by

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: I ended up changing the file name to the file location and it seems to be running... I used C:/etc/etc/etc...

Comment: sounds like system dependent path to me

Comment: hmm...okay, so how would I go about changing it so anyone who ran the program would be able to access the file?

Comment: @D_Toy that will work if you execute your program in your eclipse environment pointing to one workspace. If you just move the code to a new class in a different package, then it won't work at least that you update the path, now if you even change the OS e.g. Mac or Linux, the code won't change until you update the path accordingly, so you didn't solve the problem but bypass it.

Comment: @D_Toy refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825414/best-practice-on-configuring-log4j-properties-path